# Not sure why I am getting C++ error with cin and getline

Tags: c++

I am trying to go through a CSV file that is formatted like this:

```
4305,2.7,59338,"Autauga County, AL"
14064,2.7,57588,"Baldwin County, AL"
```

Here is an adapted version of the code:

```
using namespace std;
 int main(){
    string newl;
    //getline(cin, newl);

 while(getline(cin,newl,',')){

    double cases1 = stod(newl);
    //cin.ignore();
    cout << cases1 << ' ';
    cout << "numbaone" << endl;

    getline(cin,newl,',');
    //cin.ignore();
    double unemploymentrate1 = stod(newl);
    cout << unemploymentrate1 << ' ';
    cout << "numbatwo" << endl;


    getline(cin,newl,',');
    double income1 = stod(newl);
    cout << income1 << ' ';
    cout << "numbathree"  << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,newl);
    }
 }
```

When I just input one line it gives me the correct output which for
`1882,3.1,46064,"Bibb County, AL`" is

```
1882 numbaone   
3.1 numbatwo    
46064 numbathree
```

However, when I copy and paste multiple lines as input such as

```
1530,3.8,34382,"Barbour County, AL"
1882,3.1,46064,"Bibb County, AL"
```

the output gets really messed up:

```
1530,3.8,34382,"Barbour County, AL"
1882,31530 numbaone
3.8 numbatwo
34382 numbathree
.1,46064,"Bibb County, AL"
1882 numbaone
3.1 numbatwo
46064 numbathree
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use `getline(cin, line)` to get a line, then use `stringstream ss(line);` to parse out the line field by field.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how stringstream works; I am a fairly new user of c++

Comment: @MadhavBhat, it's not very different from reading from `cin` or a file. Checkout the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem and there is nothing obviously wrong. How do you enter input? Is it possible that your terminal just mangled the input and output?

Comment: Please be more precise in your title. You don't have a C++ error, you have a logic error. This way you might get better help.

Comment: That is possible. I copied and pasted it into the terminal. I am using VScode.

Comment: You could give it a try and write to a `std::stringstream` or to a file instead.

Comment: This is most likely related to how your terminal handles copy/paste, input, and output. I suggest not copying and pasting multiple lines to enter input. Either enter the input one line at a time or add all your input to a file and then read the data from the file.

Comment: FYI, `cin.ignore(); getline(cin,newl);` can be simplified to `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an string stream to parse data for each line .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string newl;

    while (getline(cin, newl)) {

        stringstream stream(newl);

        getline(stream, newl, ',');
        double cases1 = stod(newl);
        cout << cases1 << ' ';
        cout << "numbaone" << endl;

        getline(stream, newl, ',');
        double unemploymentrate1 = stod(newl);
        cout << unemploymentrate1 << ' ';
        cout << "numbatwo" << endl;

        getline(stream, newl, ',');
        double income1 = stod(newl);
        cout << income1 << ' ';
        cout << "numbathree" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```